# Oracle group by hh:mm column

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column in format HH:MM with records in intervals of 5 minutos

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ Hour  ║ MyVals ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║ 00:00 ║      1 ║
║ 00:05 ║      2 ║
║ 00:10 ║      3 ║
║ 00:15 ║      4 ║
║ 00:20 ║      5 ║
║ 00:25 ║      6 ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

I would like to group values every 15 minutes, like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ Hour  ║ MyVals ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║ 00:00 ║      6 ║
║ 00:15 ║     15 ║
║ 00:30 ║     24 ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT 
   regexp_substr(hora, '\d\d:(00|15|30|45)', 1, 1, 'i') as Hour, 
   sum(MyVals)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Hour, MyVals
```

but it only get values where hour finishes in 00, 15, 30 or 45, not group then.
There is a way to make this work with regex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the hour into the `date` and then group them with an interval of the 15 minutes as follows:

```
SQL> -- YOUR DATA
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE (HOUR, MYVALS) AS
  2  (SELECT  '00:00',      1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT  '00:05',      2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT  '00:10',      3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT  '00:15',      4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT  '00:20',      5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT  '00:25',      6 FROM DUAL)
  8  -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
  9  SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(TO_DATE(HOUR,'HH24:MI')),'HH24:MI') AS DT,
 10         SUM(MYVALS) FROM YOUR_TABLE
 11  GROUP BY FLOOR((TO_DATE(HOUR,'HH24:MI') - TRUNC(TO_DATE(HOUR,'HH24:MI'))) * 24*60/ 15)
 12  ORDER BY DT;

DT    SUM(MYVALS)
----- -----------
00:00           6
00:15          15

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

You might homogenize your times with a 'case' statement using 'like' or substr=, folding the values to the right 15 minute time for :05, :10, :20, etc., less processing intense than regex.

Or you can rebuild the strings using a math solution by converting the last 2 digits to a number and doing an integer divide, multiply, convert back to string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXTRACT function instead of REGEXP_SUBSTR but if you really really want to use REGEXP_SUBSTR than try below.

```
WITH test
     AS (SELECT '19-Jun-2018 05:15:15' txt, 1 AS VAL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '19-Jun-2018 05:00:16' txt, 2 AS VAL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '19-Jun-2018 05:35:35' txt, 3 AS VAL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '19-Jun-2018 05:45:45' txt, 4 AS VAL FROM DUAL)
  SELECT CASE
            WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '00'
                 AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '16'
            THEN
               '00:15'
            WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '15'
                 AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '31'
            THEN
               '00:30'
            WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '30'
                 AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '45'
            THEN
               '00:45'
            ELSE
               'FALSE'
         END
            KEYZ,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '00'
                    AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '16'
               THEN
                  VAL
               WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '15'
                    AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '31'
               THEN
                  VAL
               WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '30'
                    AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '45'
               THEN
                  VAL
               ELSE
                  0
            END)
            SUMM
    FROM (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt, '([0-9]{2,2}):([0-9]{2,2}):([0-9]{2,2})')
                    HHMMSS,
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt, '([0-9]{2,2}):([0-9]{2,2})') HHMM,
                 VAL
            FROM test)
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '00'
                 AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '16'
            THEN
               '00:15'
            WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '15'
                 AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '31'
            THEN
               '00:30'
            WHEN     SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) >= '30'
                 AND SUBSTR (HHMM, LENGTH (HHMM) - 1, 2) < '45'
            THEN
               '00:45'
            ELSE
               'FALSE'
         END
```

Comment: Edited my answer. You can use this query as you like i think. @HarisonSilva